# Truth table and logic circuit problem

Tags: boolean-algebra

Does anyone know how to make this into a truth table and a logic circuit?

(x•y)+x

If so please send me the answer.

Comment: This simplifies to just $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Create  a list of all possible (combinations) values for each of your variables, in this case, (x,y).  See below for the headers.  Remember a single variable can take either True or False.

X | Y | (X.Y) | (X.Y) + X

From them on you only need to carry out the operations outlined for each of those possible values: the dot is logical and the plus is the logical or.